# Using mod_rewrite with multiple Drupal installations

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a website with Drupal installed in a subfolder */drupal*. This instance needs to handle all URLs for the site, which it does successfully with the rules below:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^131.216.164.200:10011$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://131.216.164.200:10011/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

However, I now need to add another Drupal folder, */otherdrupal*, which will handle **only** URLs beginning with */something1* or */something2*. What I've tried is modifying the rules to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^131.216.164.200:10011$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://131.216.164.200:10011/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(something1|something2)$ otherdrupal/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/otherdrupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* otherdrupal/$0 [L]
```

But mod_rewrite is not gonna make it that easy...

(P.S. I'm aware of Drupal's multi-site feature, but assume that the second Drupal instance may be any web application that handles URLs the same way as Drupal does, e.g. with a `q` URL parameter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My working .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^131.216.164.200:10011$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://131.216.164.200:10011/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/something1|/something2)
RewriteRule .* otherdrupal/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```